# Why does 'inspect' print the array but not using 'inspect' puts each element?

Tags: arrays, ruby, multidimensional-array

I have a nested array:

```
array_name = [
  ["Alice", "pizza", "soccer"],
  ["Steve", "sushi", "hockey"],
  ["Alex", "pasta", "none"]
]
```

When I use `inspect` in a loop:

```
array_name.each do |i|
  puts i.inspect
end
```

it outputs:

```
["Alice", "pizza", "soccer"]
["Steve", "sushi", "hockey"]
["Alex", "pasta", "none"]
```

but using `puts` instead prints every element from every individual array:

```
array_name.each do |i|
  puts i
end
```

outputs:

```
Alice
pizza
soccer
Steve
sushi
hockey
Alex
pasta
none
```

Why does `array_name.inspect` output the entire array like above?

I read that `inspect` tries to print the coded version. I don't get, then, why the following shows the same output as the second code above:

```
array_name.each do |i|
  i.each do |sub_i|
    puts sub_i
  end
end
```

outputs:

```
Alice
pizza
soccer
Steve
sushi
hockey
Alex
pasta
none
```

The second and the third codes above give me the same output, which is not the array but the actual elements inside every array. Why is this?

Comment: `puts array_name` would display all elements on separate lines as well.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Actually, this is how method [puts](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.5.0/IO.html#method-i-puts) behave. From documentation:

> If called with an array argument, writes each element on a new line. Each given object that isn't a string or array will be converted by calling its to_s method. If called without arguments, outputs a single newline.

On the other hand, there `p` method in Ruby:

> For each object, directly writes obj.inspect followed by a newline to the program’s standard output.

The following code will print the result you're expecting:

```
array_name.each do |i|
  p i
end
```

Comment: Ahhh, okay, this course I'm doing only covered ```puts``` so I wasn't aware there was a separate method for specifically showing the array, thank you for the clarification!